# JavaFX - how to add all files from directory to TableView

Tags: file, user-interface, javafx, filechooser

Title says all. I want to directory of files to be read and then write to TableView. How to do this? I thought about treating files and folders in choosen directory as array and then open and add them one by on through loop but I don't know how to translate this into java, standard libraries doesn't include helpfull methods except opening single file/directory.

Comment: You want the table to display a list of the files? Or the contents of the files, in some way?

Comment: Yes, i'm writing music player now in JavaFX so that's the case. I want to click in DirectoryChooser on "Music" folder and then add every sub folder with mp3's

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the files in a directory:

```
TableView<File> table = new TableView<>();
// configure table columns etc
File dir = ... ;
table.getItems().addAll(dir.listFiles());
```

If you want to recursively go through sub-directories (to a given depth), use the java.nio API:

```
TableView<Path> table = new TableView<>();
// configure table columns etc

File fileDir = directoryChooser.showDialog(mainStage);
if (fileDir != null) { // if the user chose something:
    Path dir = fileDir.toPath() ;
    int depth = ... ; // maximum depth to search, use Integer.MAX_VALUE to search everything
    Files.find(dir, depth, (path, attributes) -> 
        path.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3")) // select only mp3 files
        .forEach(table.getItems()::add);
}
```

In the last (long) statement, `Files.find(...)` produces a (Java 8) `Stream<Path>`. The code invokes `forEach(...)` on that stream, to add each element to the `items` in a table view.

Comment: But where I should assign File variable where selected directory is stored?

Comment: Wherever you need it. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: According to second, recursive method. I don't see any file variable. Sorry for silly question but this API is comepletly new to me. It's like I open directory in DirectoryChooser, then get this Files.find method fired and that's it?

Comment: In the java.nio API, use `Path` in place of `File`. `File` defines a `toPath()` method (and vice-versa), so you can do `File file = directoryChooser.showDialog(...);` and `if (file != null) { Path dir = file.toPath(); ...}`

Comment: Thank you, now it's understandable to me. One more thing, before I add file to TableView, I need to get some mp3 metadata like artist, album name etc from method. To do that, i have to have every file in File type. How get each found by .find element back from Path type to File again? I know that is managable by .toFile method but in your code I can't find place to put it.

Comment: `Files.find(...).map(Path::toFile)` will convert the `Stream<Path>` to a `Stream<File>`. Then you can call `forEach(...)` and operate on each `File`.