# JavaFX SceneBuilder List of Computers' Data

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Let's say I've got a folder on my Desktop with some mp3s, can I create a list in ScenBuilder which shows every mp3 as an element, without manually adding each one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX - how to add all files from directory to TableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042665/javafx-how-to-add-all-files-from-directory-to-tableview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a list.

Use a [DirectoryChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html) to get the path where your music is stored,
with the [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class create a list of all the music, use a [ListView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm) and populate it with the music list.

and there you have it.